# Visual Studio Community 2013 Release mode performance issues?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio, opengl

I am working on an engine and during a 50k entity test, while running on Debug Mode my FPS is stable around 80. Once I go to Release Mode, however, my FPS starts at around 1100 and goes down to about 640 after 5 seconds, and then a second after that it goes down to a stable 540.

This is very strange because the FPS gets halved only on my computer. Trying this on my some of my other computers, the FPS is lower (worse computer), but very stable and still above my 540 fps that it goes down to.

This is a C++ OpenGL Engine using GLEW and GLFW. On Release, these are the settings I have changed:

- Optimization: Maximize Speed
- Inline Function Expansion: Any Suitable
- Enable Intrinsic Functions: Yes
- Favor Size Or Speed: Favor fast code
- Enable Enhanced Instruction Set: Streaming SIMD Extensions 2
- Floating Point Model: Fast

Everything else (other than the things required for GLEW and GLFW) is default.

I have, however, turned off everything I changed and the the same things still happen. Because of this, it is likely something from the the default Release Mode settings.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you dynamically allocating memory frequently or once?  You should only allocate the frame buffers during initialization.

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler? Except wild guesses, I don't see, how people should be able to answer your question whithout access to your code and your machine.

Comment: What processor are you targeting? x64? Since you're telling the compiler to use SSE2, you may want to enforce 16-byte alignment. Alignment does not much matter performance wise in many debug builds because of the amount of overhead incurred elsewhere, but it can have a huge impact (~40% penalty for misaligned vs. aligned access) in shipped software. x64 defaults to 16-byte alignment in MSVC. x86 to 8-byte (for dynamically allocated memory). The former is really SSE-friendly, the latter not so much.

Comment: That is a wild guess though, this problem is impossible to diagnose without actual pinpointed performance numbers like you would get running it through a profiler. If you can point out some code that is running slowly in Release vs. Debug, then we might be able to help you.

Comment: Your framerate drop sounds pretty bad, but if you actually look at the frame time, you're only losing 0.65ms (1100fps = 0.91ms, 650fps = 1.5ms) and 0.29ms (540fps = 1.85ms).

This is such a minor thing that you're going to have to do some profiling to see what's going on, but I wouldn't worry about it, unless you have some insane fps requirements. 0.65ms is the difference between 57.7fps and 60fps

Comment: Yeah I know I'm kinda over-worried about it but I don't like how worse computers than mine have a higher stable FPS than I do. I'll look for a better profiler to try and get some more useful info.

Comment: Wild idea: hardware problem? Processor goes into Turbo mode, quickly overheats and steps down? I would vacuum my vents :)

Comment: No it isn't because of that, After continuous testing it always happens after 5 seconds, also I regularly clean my computer and temps are kept low enough with my cooler so that it shouldn't throttle even after insane benchmarks and stress tests.